How unlock -ffast-math for my custom type?
Question
How can I enhance the algebraic efficiency of my code for a custom implemented type?
Is there maybe a virtual empty type from which I can inherit that will tell the compiler that this is fast-math stuff? Or is there a compile-time type that somebody implemented that provides all these expression templates.
Upfront remark: For anyone who makes assumptions on the compile time and run-time, these assumptions are wrong. There are two sequential passes of compilation and execution.
The first pass is compiling and running an initial_source.cpp . This program will upon execution write an essay called generated_program.cpp .
The essay will not change no matter what compiler options are used.
Next, the generated_program.cpp is compiled and run. I care about the performance of this last run. As it turns out, when the initial_source.cpp is algebraically concise, then the generated_program.cpp is shorter and faster.
For the math nerds: Any distinct but algebraic equivalent initial_source.cpp files will create distinct but algebraic equivalent generated_program.cpp`` files (when ignoring round-off errors).
So now what I want to tell the compiler is not:

yeah there are some index shifts when processing the strings and other basic types when you compile and run the initial_source.cpp so please go optimize that for me.

But instead:

do you see these algebraic expressions there with some ominous number type you know nothing about? Treat these like they were double, that is, rearrange them for most concise expressions. And then compile the code please in any slow way you want.

Context
I have a custom type Number that can be treated like a double or float, etc. .
Given any function
template<typename Tfloat>
void f(Tfloat* y, Tfloat* x){ ... }

I can call it with my custom type and therefrom generate other code. (think of adjoints, tangents, adjacency matrices, graphs, etc). I like the generated code best if it is cheap to evaluate, but its length and efficiency dramatically depend on subtleties within f.
Now, if a line within f reads
auto z1 =  (x-(-y));
auto z2 = -(x-(-y));
auto z3 = 1+x+2+3+4;
auto z4 = cos(-x);
auto z5 = -sin(-x);

then I am sure we all agree that is is inferior to
auto z1 =  x+y;
auto z2 = -z1;
auto z3 = x+(1+2+3+4);
auto z4 = cos(x);
auto z5 = sin(x);

The first version may result in an adjoint tape that is twice as long in terms of code text, requires twice the amount memory, and is in consequence ten times slower than the code generated from the second version.
Yet, naturally, the compiler will not touch any algebraic expressions and assignments that involve my number, simply because it cannot even tell whether addition commutes for my type.
I know how to implement expression templates; but this would mean an incredible amount of work. Given that the compiler is so excellent in doing just this kind of work for standard types, it would be incredibly stupid if I spent my time to just try to reproduce an inferior version of that, even more so as the algebra is just a tiny detail in what my actual project task is.
Remarks
Anything is better than nothing
I am aware that "the optimal" algebraic version of any program depends on the implementation details of my Number, but it is perfectly fine for us to assume that the relative cost per operation is equal to as for double (i.e., add is way cheaper than mul unless FMA, and no sign-switch is cheaper than yes sign-switch). And if that involves too many issues, the spirit is: I just need something that is better than what I have and does not reinvent the wheel (i.e., I won't implement expression templates for sign-switch and order of sum & prod).
The compiler will for a fact not optimize the algebra of custom types (that is the whole reason of the question)
Since many algebraic objects do not commute (e.g. matrices in multiplication), the compiler will not optimize the expression for z3, even x is as heavy as a matrix and we just want to add a constant to each term, as per the operator overload. Likewise, the compiler will not replace x-(-y) with x+y because nothing is stopping a developer from implementing the unary minus operator from not being its own inverse operator.
If a compiler was all-knowing, in principle the generated code (which is flat, e.g. all types are double) could be optimized by the compiler to the same level of mastery as the code generated from an algebraically optimized initial code, because, after all, the two generated codes are likewise algebraically equivalent (that is, before round-off). Yet, real-world compilers produce much slower code from generated code of an algebraically poor initial code version.
Helping with Confusion in the Chat
Some readers believe the compiler will ultimately optimize both generated codes to same level. To break this down, let's start from the original code. Suppose a Number that just prints a different string on the monitor for every operation taking place. Naturally, the compiler -- regardless what optimization option -- will not change that monitor output. Conclusively, tapes, text files, generated codes, created from the run of the initial code with the custom type Number will result in the same code, regardless what optimizations are being used. That highlights the issue with z3.
Next, let's look into adjoints. For adjoints, each operation creates at least one number on the tape to be stored with a derivative computation taking place later on in the reverse order of the tape. It is not unrealistic to picture code here that is several 100k lines long. I don't care how awesome your compiler is. It will not identify that skipping two operations with two elements on the tape that are 100k lines apart in an entirely nonlinear piece of incomprehensible auto-code can be removed due to algebraic equivalence. That is just not what compilers do. They analyze code locally. Again, in theory all generated assembly code is equivalent so under best optimization would be identical (in case the optimal solution is unique), but I am interested in a real-world solution.
Example on the Non-Equivalence
Suppose
void f(Tfloat& y, Tfloat& x){ y = 1+x+2+3+4; }

This will create the following adjoint c++ code file:
void gf(Tfloat& y, Tfloat& x, Tfloat& gy, Tfloat& gx){
auto tmp1 = 1+x;
auto tmp2 = tmp1+1;
auto tmp3 = tmp2+2;
y         = tmp3+3;
auto gtmp3+= gy;
auto gtmp2+= gtmp3;
auto gtmp1+= gtmp2;
gx += gtmp1;
}

In contrast, an algebraically optimized initial version of the code would yield the following distinct tape:
void gf(Tfloat& y, Tfloat& x, Tfloat& gy, Tfloat& gx){
y = x+(1+2+3+4);
gx += gy;
}

Admittedly, when taking both generated pieces of code, then the perfect compiler could produce identically optimized code from both of them. But in a real world and for much much much much bigger files, this just is not the case.

Have you verified that the compiler is not able to perform these transformations? Given inline definitions, it doesn’t seem like anything would be stopping it, presuming the functions do  basically the same operations.

@Sneftel . Yes, I know for a fact that the compiler does not touch any expressions involving custom types. Maybe the easiest to see, have a look at z3: The compiler will evaluate the additions from left to right unless bracketed otherwise, thus 1+x creates an object of Number which then is added term by term to an object of Number. That is of course far far slower than lumping the constants into the right-hand side. I even went as far as adding requirements as to enforce disciplined programming, but seriously there is only so much you can do without ruining user experience.

“the compiler does not touch any expressions involving custom types” - well, that’s definitely not true. The optimizer doesn’t care about your types, just your operations. Once boiled down to SSA, why would you expect it to fail to apply these sorts of peephole opts? Have you checked the assembly?

The compiler will optimize these after templates are expanded.

But if you want ffast-math just for certain types I believe you can implement specialized instances for the appropriate types in their own source file then just compile that file with ffast-math.

Please everyone: Why is it non-obvious to see that the ultimate assembly codes are distinct? Please help me understand why you think that. For instance, let's say I divide x/y and due to order of evaluation y is either a Number or a double, the resulting tapes for the derivative of the expression "x/y" will not even be algebraically equivalent because numbers are going to be introduced on the tape that are fed from external. Yeah, just why would you feel so sure in this misconception? Sorry, don't meant sassy; but it's utterly wrong and defies the question.

If the compiler sees the underlying instructions on primitive types, meaning your abstraction layer is made from inline functions OR you compile with link-time-optimization, then the compiler can optimize it fully. The code will be inlined, the abstraction disappears, the compiler does its job (assuming -ffast-math or similar are active). If your abstraction is a fully-fledged external function call, then you are right and the compiler cannot optimize much. Which scenario applies to your code?

Remember that a template isn't compiled, its separate instantiations are. https://godbolt.org/z/oG4WvoxY6 demonstrates --fast-math affects a template function.

@Homer512 . Thank you first of all for acknowledging the possibility of legitimacy of my question!! I really mean it. I think the issue is that there are two run-times: 1) where the initial code is run and writes text files of other code. 2) the other code that is then compiled and run. The issue is that the first code does not know anything about the second code. Also, the second code is much much longer than the first and thus harder for a compiler to optimize. Finally, an expression like "x-(-y)" actually writes adds computations into the second code which the compiler of first cannot see.

I'm still confused. Where is this second text file coming from? Did you implement a code generator and want it to optimize? Or do you mean the different phases of compilation, intermediate representations etc.?

@Homer512 . It is a text file produced by the program that is compiled from the first cpp file. The first file contains template function f. The function f is typically written by a consumer. They then press play and f is compiled, run, and its adjoint code generated in the background. The adjoint will then be compiled and ran within an optimization algorithm that creates a solution to the customer's application f.

Okay, so the compilation happens at a point where the function f is known. Which means, if it is inline (or LTO), the compiler can reason about its behavior, right? Or is the part that you want optimized pre-compiled?

@Homer512 You are correct: Nothing is precompiled. Everything is header-only. But still, the generated code which is 99% of the entire code for the second program, has been created automatically from a very poor initial code. Theoretically, the compiler could undo all the harm done (yet with significant increase of compile time), but I distrust its practical capability of doing so. We have to not forget that algebraic optimization is an NP-problem and all the compiler does here is mere heuristics. Undoubtedly, heuristics spent on the initial code are superior to heuristics only on the second.

From the perspective of the compiler, there is only one code. It will do its optimization passes, which includes inlining and then doing most of its optimizations on primitive types and instructions. Is your question whether you can help the compiler along by declaring semantics or algebraic identities? Then the answer is no, not really. restrict pointers, function attributes, std::expected and [[assume(...)]] can help. That's about all

@Homer512 Oh and I think I even misunderstood you still, because no: the type of the number (e.g. double, float, Eigen::matrix<double,3,3> etc) used in the second program is invisible to the compiler of the first program because the templates are not instantiated (even when in fact these types are implemented in the same header files); but the compiler cannot interpret that because it ultimately compiles a program that writes an essay (which is the program text of the second program).

Okay, if you work with an opaque, abstract type and non-inline functions, then the compiler can do very little, other than the few things I listed. What you could do is run the initial code through a symbolic solver during your code generation stage, e.g. pipe your expressions through simpy and generate code from its simplified output. These solvers of course simply assume that the variables behave like scalars, matrices, etc

@Homer512 . Yes. I considered that. It just would mean a lot of human-in-the-loop because most code in f is invalid outside the framework. So what you propose would really just work in snippets. It feels wrong to me that the compiler obviously does algebraic optimization, yet does not let me access it. Or is this POV technically inaccurate?

I think it's more a matter of scope. The high-level for high level languages like C++ is rather low-level by modern standards. Most applications that require user-provided code also solve the issue with JIT compilation via LLVM or similar projects. OpenCL kernels or GPU shaders are prime examples of that
